# Capture HTML value and place inside img src attribute

Tags: javascript, html

How would I capture the all the numbers after the semi colon : in this code?

Ignore this **rgFHTeVZ-4444322794**, it only appears because I'm working on a preview link.

```
<p id="productName">rgFHTeVZ-4444322794Diecut model number: 110</p>
```

the productName is dynamically added from the URL parameter in this script below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // start by creating a function 
    function loadUp(){
        var str = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(/(?:(\D+=))/ig, "")) //get the search parameters from the url and remove everything before the "=" sign
        
        document.getElementById('productName').innerHTML = str //assign that string to the "innerHTML" of the h1 tag that has an id of "productName"
    };

    window.onload = loadUp; // once the page has loaded, fire off that function
</script>
```

I want to take those numbers and use them to dynamically add to a img src attribute so the image would change based on the parameter.

The 110 is what I would like to dynamically change.

the img src looks like this: https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubf/43534/asset-diecut/sampleImage/110_a.png

any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm unsure of where to start.

Comment: Look at [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) get contents of div as string
2) split string into array broken on :
3) assign div new innerHTML
```

```js
let text = document.getElementById('productName').innerHTML

let textArray = text.split(': ')

document.getElementById('productName').innerHTML = (textArray[1]).trim()
```

```html
<p id="productName">rgFHTeVZ-4444322794Diecut model number: 110</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split(":")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert it to an array:

```
Array ["Diecut model number", " 110"]
```

Then simply pick index 1.

```
document.getElementById('productName').innerHTML = str.split(":")[1];
```

*you can use [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove white-spaces

```
str.split(":")[1].trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach you can use for this.

You can always use RegEx for this scenario as long as its always on the last digits

```js
let array = document.getElementById('productName').innerHTML;
let output = document.getElementById('output');


let num = array.match(/\d+$/g); // or if combination of Letter or number => (/\w+$/g);
output.innerHTML = num[0];
```

```html
<p id="productName">rgFHTeVZ-4444322794Diecut model number: 110</p>

<div id="output"></div>
```